# javascript php mysql flot

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, flot

I encountered a new problem regarding my x-axis. My intention was to output a x-axis which indicates the time, while the y axis indicates the power. I decided to use `time[i]` and using `graph.push([time[i], power[i])`. However,my graph remains empty. I did an alert to output function and this was the result I got:

```
({1:"14:36", 2:"14:39", 3:"14:42", 4:"14:45", 5:"14:48", 6:"14:51", 7:"14:54", 8:"14:57"})
```

It's in `hour: mins`. What should I change to obtain a time X-axis?

```
$(function () {
var graph = [];
var power = <?php echo json_encode($data);?>;
var time = <?php echo json_encode($times);?>;
var row = <?php echo json_encode($nrow);?>;
//alert(time.toSource());


for (var i = 1; i < row; i += 1) {

    //var test = time[i];
    //alert(test);
    graph.push([time[i], power[i]]);

}

var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
       [ { data: graph, label: "Power" } ], {
           series: {
               lines: { show: true },
               points: { show: true }
           },
           grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
           yaxis: { min: 0, max: 25 }


         });
```

Comment: I have isolated any errors from variables row and power. I think the cause is due to the time[i]. any ideas anyone?

Comment: I would like to addvmore information to my question above. The time array will contain the values retrieve from the data base. Meaning to say, the x axis can be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert time from hour:mins to number

```
for (var i = 1; i < row; i += 1) {

    //var test = time[i];
    //alert(test);

    var hhmm = time[i].split(":");

    var hh = parseInt(hhmm[0]);
    var mm = parseInt(hhmm[1])/60;
    var tt = hh + mm;

    graph.push([tt, power[i]]);

}
```

EDIT ( Eugene Wong) :

//var options = {
  //  xaxis: { ticks:[[1,time[1]],[2,time[2]],[3,time[3]],[4,time[4]],[5,time[5]],[6,time[6]],[7,time[7]],[8,time[8]]]}
//};
//alert(options.toSource());

```
var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), 
       [ { data: graph, label: "Power" } ], {
           series: {
               lines: { show: true },
               points: { show: true }
           },
           grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
           yaxis: { min: 0, max: 25 },
           xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat:"%hh:%mm" }
           //xaxis: { ticks:[[1,time[1]],[2,time[2]],[3,time[3]],[4,time[4]],[5,time[5]],[6,time[6]],[7,time[7]],[8,time[8]]]}


       });
```

EDIT(Diode):

Even though  I have created time charts before, this time setting x-axis configuration didn't work. Anyway I have fixed this by adding a tick formatter function. See the code below. 'graph' is the sample data array I used.

```
    var graph = [[14.5, 10], [16.45, 15], [18.45, 20]];


    var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
       [ { data: graph, label: "Power" } ], {
           series: {
               lines: { show: true },
               points: { show: true }
           },
           grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
           yaxis: { min: 0, max: 25 },
           xaxis: {
                        min:14,
                        max:20,
                        tickSize:0.5,
                        tickFormatter: function(value){
                            var hours = Math.floor(value);
                            hours = (hours < 10)?"0"+hours:hours;
                            var minutes = (value - hours) * 60;
                            minutes = (minutes < 10)?"0"+minutes:minutes;
                            return hours + ":" + minutes;
                        }
                     }



         });
```

Comment: is it possible if I represent it as 14:32...like a string?

Comment: Ya it is possible. In data you have to give the time as number, but you can specify the label format of x axis like this 
`xaxis: {
                  mode: "time",
                  timeformat:"%h:%m"
                
               }`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. At the moment, I still can't output that data on the x axis. This is my updated script.
   for (var i = 1; i < row; i += 1) {

    //var test = time[i];
    //alert(test);

    var hhmm = time[i].split(":");

    var hh = parseInt(hhmm[0]);
    var mm = parseInt(hhmm[1])/60;
    var tt = hh + mm;

    graph.push([tt, power[i]]);


}

//var options = {
  //  xaxis: { ticks:[[1,time[1]],[2,time[2]],[3,time[3]],[4,time[4]],[5,time[5]],[6,time[6]],[7,time[7]],[8,time[8]]]}
//};
//alert(options.toSource());

Comment: I have modified the code. Please the updated answer. This is working.

Comment: Hey diode, thanks for the prompt reply! It works! I was thinking of another method, i.e var options = {
    xaxis: { ticks:[[1,time[1]],[2,time[2]],[3,time[3]],[4,time[4]],[5,time[5]],[6,time[6]],[7,time[7]],[8,time[8]]]}
};

Comment: var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), 
           [ { data: graph, label: "Power" } ], {
               series: {
                   lines: { show: true },
                   points: { show: true }
               },
               grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
               yaxis: { min: 0, max: 25 }, options});

Comment: However, it can't plot out, any idea why?

Comment: Note that the syntax is `$.plot(placeholder, data, options)`. You can give x-axis settings after `grid` or `y-axis`. You have given `options` as fourth parameter.

Comment: hi diode, could you explain to me this statement? hours = (hours < 10)?"0"+hours:hours; minutes = (minutes < 10)?"0"+minutes:minutes;

Comment: its just a formatting, to show 00 for 0, 01 for 1 ... 09 for 9.

Comment: Thanks Diode for your help! If there's anymore question on this, is it ok if I ask you about it?

Answer (score 0):

Have PHP output a Javascript timestamp instead of the already formatted date/time.  Just remember a few caveats about timestamps:

- [PHP timestamps](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) are seconds, whereas javascript ones are milliseconds, so multiply by 1000
- flot plots in UTC time, so you may need to convert your timestamp to UTC before outputting
- There is a good example of time series data on the [flot website](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/time.html).

Remember to specify `xaxis: { mode: "time" }` in your flot options.

Comment: I saw this in one of the flot example i.e [-373597200000, 315.71], [-370918800000, 317.45],

this value was used in as part of the timestamp. However, I got no idea how to link the value to the x axis. For example, -370918800000 was indicated at the year 1960s. What does this value represent?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on in those timestamps, but if you are using mode "time" then the xaxis actually represents time, i.e. you can just put javascript timestamps in the spot of an x axis value.