# Time isn't displaying in Flot chart

Tags: javascript, flot

I have these in my data1.csv. The left column is time and the right column is the data. I would like to display time on x-axis and the data on y-axis on flot chart.

```
09:35,13
10:35,12
11:35,38
12:35,12
13:35,11
14:35,10
15:35,43
16:35,42
17:35,39
18:35,45
```

I have done the function to load my data and no problem there.

```
function graphUpdate() {
            $.ajax({
                url : "file/data1.csv",
                type : "GET",
                dataType : "text",
                success : oncsvReceived
            });
        }
```

Now my problem is to display those time on x-axis on flot charts as you can see below. Anyone is able to help me here? Tried reading the documentation and looking around here, it doesn't help me much. I would be very grateful for your help.

```
function oncsvReceived(data) {
    var alltext = $.csv()(data);
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [alltext], {
                 yaxis: {

                 },
                                 xaxis:{
                                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the time plugin for flot and set `mode` as `time`

See doc: https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes

update :

A few months ago, I used it by downloading separately. But I am not sure about the latest version. Please see API.txt to check whether there is any change.

link: https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.time.js

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but in the flot v0.7 zip file I downloaded, it doesn't have the time plugins. Do I have to download it separately?

Comment: Tried it but I can't seem to make it work. I have to look more into it.

Comment: please make a jsfiddle demo and share if possible

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't seem to make it work on jsfiddle. The best I can do is to give you my source code so that you can have a go at it. [link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-vUV5vGQxA2OEEwMkRsQ2hGU1k)

Comment: oh.. there are a lot of files.. please see whether you can share only the part you are working

Comment: also see whether this one is helpful.. one question I answered a few months ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612981/javascript-php-mysql-flot/8613759#8613759

Comment: Hi @Diode , following the answer from link on the question that you answered I managed to display the time as I wanted to. Thank you so much for your help!